# Can we identify if WCF Request is coming from our Silverlight APP or some place else?

Tags: wcf, silverlight

Can we identify if WCF Request is coming from our Silverlight APP or some place else?

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly declare a [MessageContract] and define a header in there, which your Silverlight app could set to a known, defined value.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

The headers should already have requester info in them, and you should be bale to parse it out and tick up a counter or whatever on the server side. I would think marc_s's suggestion of MessageContract would be the simpler solution however.